# Render() is called before ComponentWillmount(), Can't get show data on first attempt

Tags: react-native, render

**I want to show user profile in my react native app. I get the userinfo from another component but now I can't show the data on first attempt. Render() is called before componentWillmount() so the first time I click on profile, data is undefined, but when I go back to home page and click again I see the userinfo.
I already tried to set a state and stop rendering until data is loaded but didn't work**

```
 var data = [];
    class Profiel extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props)
    this.state={fetching:false};

      }

       componentWillMount() {

        SInfo.getItem("userdata",{}).then( JsonData => {
            data = JSON.parse(JsonData)
          console.log(data.nickname)   //Show secon
        });
        this.setState({fetching:true});

               }

      render() {
        console.log('render ' + data.nickname)  //shows first

        if(!this.state.fetching){
          return null;
        }
        return (

          <Text>{data.nickname}</Text>
          <Text>{data.email}</Text>
          <Text>{data.age}</Text>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior, render is called so you can offer user feedback while loading something in the background, you should show something to the user like an [activity indicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator) to let them know your app has not crashed and is fetching data.

In your will mount method, you are making an asynchronous call and waiting for the response with "then", but you call `this.setState({fetching:true});` outside the promise return, this means that it is being called as soon as the data fetch is being called so it renders the wrong state without the data, try placing it inside your promise resolution:

```
componentWillMount() {
    SInfo.getItem("userdata",{}).then( JsonData => {
        data = JSON.parse(JsonData)
        console.log(data.nickname)   //Show secon
        this.setState({fetching:true});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, did the job for me :)